# Is there an way to programmatically read a file from a TrueCrypt disk into memory?

Tags: truecrypt

I need to load a file from an umounted TrueCrypt disk into memory.  Is there any way to do this programmatically?  Does TrueCrypt offer an API?

The way I believe is best for attempting this would be to mount the volume (prompting the user for a password, of course), open the file, and then unmount the volume.  Is there a way to do this all automatically?

I am on Windows Vista.  I have C#, Python, and Perl readily available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you not use the [true crypt command line](https://www.truecrypt71a.com/documentation/command-line-usage/) from say System.Diagnostics.Process?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test {
    
    class TrueCrypeStart
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string password = getPassword(...);
            Process tc= new Process();

            tc.StartInfo.FileName   = "TrueCrypt.exe";
            tc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/v \"{0}\" /p \"{1}\" /q", ...mount info ..., password); // for quiet!

            tc.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that hardcoding the password into a .NET assembly could make it easy to extract the pw by decompiling it. You should consider obfuscating your code if security is an issue.

Comment: @galaktor - I solved that problem by omitting the /p option, allowing the user to input the password themselves directly into TrueCrypt.

Comment: But sending a password like this can be a problem because the password will be visible as pure-text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279436/see-command-line-arguments-being-passed-to-a-program

Comment: @nav - All plain text can be a problem. This why you mitigate risk using further levels of security. For example you could avoid harcoding or use keyrings, or perhaps hardware keys. etc. etc.

Comment: @Preet: Thanks. In this case, would it be possible to encrypt the password (or the entire commandline string) in some way to ensure that truecrypt can be invoked from a C++ app without revealing the password?

Comment: @Nav - not sure - you will have to not invoke the .exe as a process,  rather you'll have see if you can use the code directly.

Comment: @Preet. Thanks, but using the code has the restriction that I'll have to publish my code. That's what the license says, and I can't do that.

Comment: @Nav - then you'll have to consider an alternative such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432816/truecrypt-alternative-with-api

Answer (score 0):

[TrueResize](http://iknowu.dnsalias.com/files/public/TrueResize/TrueResize.htm) includes an open-source C# TrueCrypt library that will allow you to read the encrypted volume (without having to mount it), an additional library includes NTFS support.