# Is it possible to use TrueCrypt through another application? (C#)

Tags: c#, security, windows-7, truecrypt

I have just started using TrueCrypt and I am wondering if it is at all possible for me to write a console/forms app that will allow me to interact with truecrypt. It would be using C# in Visual Studio 2010 with Windows 7. I am just wanting to know if I can do it. If anyone has done it before or knows if it is possible I would appreciate some input.

Thanks,

Stuart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did look (very briefly) a few months ago, and it seems that TrueCrypt has no API other than the command line.

See this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315677/is-there-an-way-to-programatically-read-a-file-from-a-truecrypt-disk-into-memor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315677/is-there-an-way-to-programatically-read-a-file-from-a-truecrypt-disk-into-memory)y as well.

Comment: From a very quick search, here are some command line options you can use http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this will be enough, it seemed to work for these guys so I'll give it a try. Thanks again