# TrueCrypt alternative with API

Tags: security, encryption, administration, truecrypt

I am searching for a TrueCrypt alternative that has an API to programmatically access the files. Does anyone know a solution?

The API should support the listing, creating, changing and deleting of files.

Comment: What OS? And I think you should be a bit more specific what API you want. For example you can call true-crypt with certain command line arguments.

Comment: Too vague at present to answer specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Diskcryptor](http://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Main_Page/en) does not have an API, but it is GPL.

If I may, I beleive what you are asking for is for a abstract file system library. I understand that you want to load a TrueCrypt or similar container and list its content. When it is opened, such a container is just raw bytes reprenting sectors. On top the the encryption, such an API would see only raw sectors and it would have to make sense of them with a corresponding sector level api.

You can see the problem in another way. How would you write a program, such as zip, that can present such information on a zip file, a very common container if you will.

[image: TrueCrypt container compared to a zip file]

So the API you are looking for would need to acheive two things :

1. Understand the container's encryption scheme (possibly multiple version of it)
2. Understand the sector format of the embeeded filesystem
3. Provide a user friendly API.

I have asked myself the same questions a while ago, scoured the net for answers, and this answer is the sum of what I have found so far. I hope you find it a valid answer, even if its not actionable.

Not yet, anyways ;)

Answer (score 1):

Our [SolFS OS Edition](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) might be what you are looking for if you plan to create new software. It's available for Windows, MacOS X, Linux and FreeBSD.

Comment: @Lena trial keys are provided to everyone. We also sell to individuals and sometimes even arrange non-commercial free licenses. Please just ask in sales.

Answer (score 1):

Java Filesystem Provider with integrated encryption : https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptofs