# See command line arguments being passed to a program

Tags: c#, security, arguments, command-line-arguments, truecrypt

You may skip this part

> I am using a batch file that I have in my thumb drive in order to
>   mount a true crypt volume. I created that batch file with the help of
>   [this link](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage). on that batch file I have the username and password
>   that I pass as arguments to trueCrypt.exe in order for it to be
>   mounted.

---

Anyways so my question is: will it be possible to see the arguments being passed to a program from a third party process? In other words, will it be possible to see the arguments being passed to this program:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static string password = "";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
            password = args[0];

        // get location where this program resides 
        var locationOfThisExe = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;


        Console.Write("Press enter to start a new instance of this program.");
        Console.Read();

        var randomArgument = new Random().NextDouble().ToString();
        Process.Start(locationOfThisExe, randomArgument); 
        // I am passing a random argument to a new process!
        // is it possible to see these arguments from another process?
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

**I am creating an edit cause I think I explained my self incorrectly but this edit should be a solution instead of a question**

I think this question has not received enough attention. Executing the command showed by https://stackoverflow.com/users/235660/alois-kraus  shows:

(I pasted the output on notepad++)

[image]

on the image it does not show very clearly but I was able to see the argument being pass to that process. **That matters a lot to me because I mount my true crypt volumes with the command:**

"C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe" /v "a:\volume.tc" /lz /a /p a

that tells to truecrypt that I want to mount the volume located at `a:\volume.tc` on drive letter z  and the password is `a`

If I execute that command true crypt will mount that volume on drive z:

[image]

the problem is that If I then execute the command `wmic process` note what shoes up:

[image]

**Note the password is in there!**

So in summary it is not safe to pass secure information as an argument. It may be secure if you close the process that received the arguments but I think it is important to be aware of this...

Comment: I don't want to say that it's not possible, but It's very irregular to do so.  what are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you looking for a system tool? [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) fits the bill.

Comment: Oh! You want to **hide** your password from showing up in there. Prefixing the most important part of your question with **You may skip this part** doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: yes is cause I have a wcf service that mounts and dismounts volumes. I just want to know how secure it is. I use a ssl sertificate to send the password to the service. But then the service has to pass the password to trueCrypt.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If other users with administrative rights or with the same user account can execute programs you can see all command lines with

```
wmic process
```

from all processes with this single command line.